# How can I cleanly distribute definitions of system functions?

Tags: parallelization, variable-definitions, contexts

I have a package that redefines a system symbol, and I am struggling to find a clean solution that will ensure that those redefinitions will still work inside a parallelized environment.

The core structure of the package is of the following form:

```
BeginPackage["Utilities`"];
f::usage = "...";
Begin["`Private`"];
f[x_] := x;
End[];
EndPackage[];
DistributeDefinitions["Utilities`"];
```

(Shamelessly stolen from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72345/), so hopefully I'm not the only one that does this.) Doing the `DistributeDefinitions` call in this way has several advantages:

- it does not attempt to launch new subkernels when they are not necessary
- it keeps the package definitions in [some mysterious place](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114283/) where they are always available for any new subkernels that get launched subsequently, even if e.g. one of them crashes and gets re-launched
- it does no harm if the package is called from inside a parallelized environment (i.e. it doesn't return errors of the form "you tried to parallelize from inside a subkernel, but this is not *Inception* and you are not Leonardo di Caprio")

Now, I want to expand this package to redefine the workings of some system symbol. For the sake of argument, suppose that I want to modify [`RandomComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomComplex.html) in the following form:

```
Unprotect[RandomComplex];
RandomComplex[{range1_List, moreRanges___}, number_] :=  Transpose[
                         RandomComplex[#, number] & /@ {range1, moreRanges}]
Protect[RandomComplex];
```

Unfortunately, even if I do this within the `BeginPackage[]` and `EndPackage[]` calls, the redefinition does not get sent to any subkernels that get launched afterwards. Thus, suppose I write this into the code above, load the package, launch some new kernels, and then run

```
ParallelEvaluate[RandomComplex[{{0, 1 + I}, {0, 1 + I}}, 3]]
```

I will then get a bunch of error messages, because each subkernel is using the unpatched version.

How can I make sure that this redefinition gets distributed downstream, ideally in a way that preserves the advantages I mentioned above, and with the least amount of pain possible.

(In particular, I can obviously run `ParallelEvaluate` on the redefinition, but then it is not stable against a subkernel crash-plus-relaunch, and it will kick and scream if I `Get` or `Needs` the package from inside a parallelized environment.)

Comment: In short: I think you *shouldn't* distribute System context symbols (or any package's context for that matter).  Instead: load the package on each subkernel (ParallelNeeds) and let it redefine the symbol on each.  I won't comment on redefining system symbols, I guess you know the dangers ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I know the dangers. I'm unsure of how to use ParallelNeeds while indicating a specific file from which to take the package, though.

Comment: My feeling is still that it's better not to distribute, as that's a nasty hack. I would use another hack: use `Get` and register it to be evaluated on newly launched kernels.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131856/12  To be fair, distribution may not be that bad, but it's a complicated thing and I don't like complicated things because they tend to cause surprises. `ParallelNeeds`, as well as registering init code is simple and predictable.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm confused as to what you're actually proposing. Should I pack a `Get` call inside some funky init code? Or should I just ask for a `ParallelNeeds`? The problem with the latter is that it does not allow me to specify the source of the package, so I have no idea how to use it in that situation.

Comment: Either install the package properly, and then you can use `ParallelNeeds` and you don't need to refer to a file.  Or use `Get` (which *can* refer to a file), and put it in some init code.  Simply load the parallel tools (evaluate `Parallelize`) then set ``Parallel`Developer`$InitCode = Hold[Get["your/file.m"]]`` before launching any kernels.  If you do not need to care about kernels which will be launched in the future in ways you cannot control, then just do `ParallelEvaluate[Get["your/file.m"]]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs wait, I just managed to get it working with the redefinition inside that Developer` code. I can see the case for a separate file if it's some sizable chunk of code, but for a few lines this should be plenty, right?